# Reporting Services - List of lists

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a report which displays the area, a list of diagnoses for the area, how many diagnoses for each diagnosis, and a percentage. This works fine, however I want to choose and display the data for many areas.

Currently, I have one choice for the area, and it shows all the diagnoses for the chosen area in a table. Essentially, I want to make a list of this tables, so it can be repeated for as many areas as required.

I think that this can be performed by putting the table in a listbox, and setting the tablix to filter for each area, but if I try this, I get:

```
Error 1 [rsInvalidDetailDataGrouping] The tablix ‘Tablix1’ has a detail member
with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.
```

It's hard to explain exactly what I need. At the moment, all the diagnoses are displayed, but they are all listed as being from the same area. I need a list of diagnoses from area 1, then a list from area 2, then area 3 etc. The percentages need to be the percentage *from that area*, currently they are the percentage of all areas.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the table in a list - just use grouping on the table.

Let's say you now want a multiple vaue parameter called `@Areas` to choose the areas and then print them all out, say separated by a page break. I assume you have something like a table for Diagnoses and a table DiagnosisItems for the items performed in a diagnosis. So your SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT Diagnoses.Area, Diagnoses.DiagnosisDate, Diagnoses.Description, 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalDiagnoses
FROM Diagnoses 
INNER JOIN DiagnosisItems ON Diagnoses.DiagnosisId = DiagnosisItems.DiagnosisId
WHERE Diagnoses.Area IN @Areas
GROUP BY Diagnoses.Area, Diagnoses.DiagnosisDate, Diagnoses.Description
ORDER BY Diagnoses.Area, Diagnoses.DiagnosisDate, Diagnoses.Description
```

Click on your table then right-click the grey handle that appears on the left hand side in the Detail row. Choose `Add Group` and group by `Area`. Add a group header and a group footer. In the table, put the `Area` in the group header and in the group footer put `Area` and the total diagnoses for that area:

```
=SUM(Fields!TotalDiagnoses.Value)
```

Now on your Detail row for the percentage you'll use an expression like this:

```
=Fields!TotalDiagnoses.Value / SUM(Fields!TotalDiagnoses.Value, "table1_Group1")
```

Right-click on the group handle, select `Row Group-Group Properties-Page Breaks` and check page breaks between each instance of a group.

Comment: You sir, are a God amongst men. Having the footer also allows me to have a total for each area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to put a filter on the tablix. Just set the grouping on the list and add the tablix.

Comment: I can't even put the table in a list though, it gives me the error above. Is making a list of tables even a valid way of doing this?